# Can the imperfect tense be used as the past tense?

Tags: temps-grammatical

Il y avait means there was but seen as it is the imperfect tense shouldn't it mean there used to be?? Does it mean both?

Comment: Yes, it's a past tense. And it can be translated by a few different past tenses in English depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

That depends, for example:

> *Il y avait une maison ici*

means both "there used to be a house" and "there was a house here".

On the other hand:

> *Il y avait un camion garé ici*

means "there was a truck parked here" while:

> There used to be a truck parked here

would be better translated by:

> *Un camion était souvent garé ici*

or

> *Il y avait un camion qui se garait ici*

Comment: ah ok That so confusing!!